# How to send a POST request to a MOXTRA API

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new to Java Script and jQuery.

I am trying to make a MOXTRA web app by accessing the Moxtra's API in which I  am trying to create a new Binder on the click of a button.

The Moxtra API console by APIGEE sends out the following request for creating a binder :-

Request

```
POST /me/binders?access_token=U1kwMQAAAUV03fjJAACowFVKRnpSbjNvWHlNS2lOTnIwdEt3UzI4AAAAAVRnRjBEN0MzdURUQ2c5OHJMQWQwb0I2YXBpZ2VlMiAgIFB HTTP/1.1

X-HostCommonName:
    api.moxtra.com

Host:
    api.moxtra.com

Content-Length:
    33

X-Target-URI:
    https://api.moxtra.com

Content-Type:
    application/json

Connection:
    Keep-Alive


{
  "name": "My First Binder"
}
```

I don't know to how make the above HTML request in jQuery or Javascript or is there any way to make the exact above request using Json. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will post this via JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: https://api.moxtra.com/me/binders?access_token=[Access-Token],
    data: {"name": "My First Binder"},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(){
       ...
    }
});
```

See : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks , I had one more doubt as to how to write  the underlying code given in the API in jquery or javass script

POST /v1/UiaduESWsbzFoK9TOldC6zF/binders

{

    "name": "My First Binder"
}


{

    "code": "RESPONSE_SUCCESS",

    "data": {

        "id": "B7U3ze39oO08PYO70973lX6",

        "name": "My First Binder",

        "revision": 3,

        "created_time": 1342813061602,

        "updated_time": 1342813061602

    }

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case? Why are you trying to create a binder? We have added lots of JavaScript sample code snippets in our developer portal. (https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/codesample/javascript-sample.html) .

You will first need to create an user and get access token before you can create the binder.

Here is how you can create the user and get access token using javascript:

```
   <!-- Include Moxtra JavaScript Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.moxtra.com/api/js/moxtra-latest.js" id="moxtrajs" data-client-id="insert_your_app_client_id"></script>

    <!-- Include External JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
    <script src="https://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

    <!-- Create Signature -->
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        var client_id = "insert_your_app_client_id";
        var client_secret = "insert_your_app_client_secret";
        var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        var unique_id = "unique_user_id"; //Unique ID of how user is identified in your system

        // HMAC-SHA-256 signature encoded using base64(URL-safe variant, RFC 4648)
        var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(client_id + unique_id + timestamp, client_secret);
        var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
        var signature = hashInBase64.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');
        // ]]>
    </script>

    <!-- Initialize user and get access token -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_token() {
            var init_options = {
                uniqueid: unique_id,
                firstname: "John",
                lastname: "Doe",
                timestamp: timestamp,
                signature: signature,
                get_accesstoken: function(result) {
                    console.log("access_token: " + result.access_token + " expires in: " + result.expires_in);
                    // Use the access token to make Moxtra SDK and API calls
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.log("error code: " + result.error_code + " message: " + result.error_message);
                }
            };
            Moxtra.setup(init_options);
        }
    </script>
```

Just invoke the get_token() function to create the user and get the access token.

Then create the binder using the access token.